# Allowing GUI updates during thread.sleep

Tags: java, swing, audio, timer, thread-sleep

I have a method that updates buttons like so:

```
public void nextQuestion() {
        //get random question
        //Take level and subtract somewhere between 66 and 0 to get a question
        randomNum = (66 * level) - ((int) (Math.random() * 66));

        question.play();
        labelQue.setText(questions.get(randomNum).getQuestionText());
        while(question.getMicrosecondLength() !=  question.getMicrosecondPosition())
        {
        }

        //AnswerA
        audioA.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        buttonA.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getA().getAnswerText());

        //AnswerB
        audioB.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        buttonB.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getB().getAnswerText());

        //AnswerC
        audioC.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        buttonC.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getC().getAnswerText());

        //AnswerD
        audioD.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        buttonD.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getD().getAnswerText());


        //Set correct to false at start of each question
        correct = false;
    }
```

However, it doesn't actually change anything in my GUI until all the sleeps and soundfiles are done playing. I'd like it to update between each sleep.

Edit: I tried using timers.

```
    //AnswerA
    Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
            audioA.play();
            buttonA.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getA().getAnswerText());
        }
    } );
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

    //AnswerB
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
            audioB.play();
            buttonB.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getB().getAnswerText());
        }
    } );
    timer2.setRepeats(false);
    timer2.start();

    //AnswerC
    Timer timer3 = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
            audioC.play();
            buttonC.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getC().getAnswerText());
        }
    } );
    timer3.setRepeats(false);
    timer3.start();

    //AnswerD
    Timer timer4 = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
            audioD.play();
            buttonD.setText(": " + questions.get(randomNum).getD().getAnswerText());
        }
    } );
    timer4.setRepeats(false);
    timer4.start();
```

However, it seems after 3 seconds, all 4 of the timers go off at the same time.

e: Changed to 3k,6k,9k,12k and works as desired!

Comment: Simple Answer:Don't sleep the EDT.

Comment: I would like for my updates not to happen until the sound file has finished playing though.

Answer (score 0):

You dot the right idea using the Swing `Timer`. But you only need *one* timer.

What you can do is put your audios into a data structure, say a `List`. I don't know of what type your audio object are so I'll just say `Audio`. So say you have a `List<Audio> audios`. What you want to do is keep a current index.

```
private int currentIndex = 0;
```

Then in the `Timer` code, you can play the first of the list, then increment the `currentIndex`

```
(audios.get(currentIndex)).play();
currentIndex++;
```

for each tick of the timer. You'll also want to check it the `currentIndex` is the size of the list, as to know when the timer should stop

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (currentIndex == audios.size()) {
        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        currentIndex = 0;  // reset for next timer start
    } else {
        // play and increment
    }
}
```

Make sure you don't `setRepeats(false)`. We *do* want it to repeat.